# Could you recommend some networking paper for me?

Tags: networking

I am learning Computer Networking this semester, on which I find it quite interesting in learning why Internet is designed like today. And I also enjoy reading paper referred to in the teaching slides, like *End-to-End Argument in System Design* and *The Design Philosophy of the DARPA Internet Protocols*.

Could you recommend some other interesting paper/articles to me, especially those related to higher layers like TCP/IP protocols?

Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roy Thomas Fielding wrote his dissertation at UCI about *Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures* (2000), which has more focus on applications in a networked environment; but I would recommend it, since it's related to your request about  *learning why Internet is designed like today*.

Link: [Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the books by Andrew Tanenbaum are worth reading. They are normally used as standard lecture in networking courses.

On the other hand, they are rather basics.

Answer (score 2):

One classic book is "Interconnections 2nd edition" by Radia Perlman.

Another very good one is "Routing in the Internet" by Christian Huitema.

If you are serious about learning how the Internet works, you also need to know about BGP. A decent introduction is "BGP4 Inter-Domain Routing in the Internet" by John Stewart.

A more advanced topic is MPLS. A very good book on this is "MPLS-Enabled Applications" by Ina Minei and Julian Lucek.

Another more advanced topic is multicast. I could recommend "Interdomain Multicast Routing" by Brian Edwards and others.

The books published by Cisco press tend to be good (although obviously vendor-specific) if you are interested in more practical details of how to configure network equipment.

Finally, "Unix Network Programming, Volume 1" by Richard Stevens is a must read if you want to do network programming.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/F05.276/papers/vegas.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but there are some really interesting papers out there on peer-to-peer networking.

Some examples:

- Chord: A Scalable Peer-to-peer Lookup Service for Internet Applications
- Incentives Build Robustness in BitTorrent
- Protecting Free Expression Online with Freenet

Answer (score 1):

If you want an introduction to **what** (not *why*) the TCP/IP protocols are, a classic book is *[TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469)*.